# Почему SUM не суммирует значения?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.

Почему SUM не суммирует результат UNION?:

Мой запрос выдает: [image: Результат запроса группировки UNION]

При том, что `SUM(count)` запроса `UNION` без группировки выдает правильное кол-во:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.code_spec_detail, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    SUM(
        CAST('SUM(count)' AS SIGNED)
    ) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            code_spec_product, 
            acc.id_subdivision, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            SUM(count) 
        FROM 
            conn_accep_detail 
            INNER JOIN acceptance acc ON acc.number = num_acc 
        WHERE 
            acc.id_subdivision != 9 
        GROUP BY 
            code_spec_product, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            acc.id_subdivision 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            code_spec_product, 
            acc.id_subdivision, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            SUM(count) 
        FROM 
            connacc_detail 
            INNER JOIN acceptance acc ON acc.number = num_acc 
        WHERE 
            acc.id_subdivision != 9 
        GROUP BY 
            code_spec_product, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            acc.id_subdivision
    ) a 
GROUP BY 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    a.code_spec_detail
```

**UPDATE**
Запрос для нужного мне результата:
[image: Правильный результат]

```
SELECT 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.code_spec_detail, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    SUM(total) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            code_spec_product, 
            acc.id_subdivision, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            SUM(count) AS total
        FROM 
            conn_accep_detail 
            INNER JOIN acceptance acc ON acc.number = num_acc 
        WHERE 
            acc.id_subdivision != 9 
        GROUP BY 
            code_spec_product, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            acc.id_subdivision 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            code_spec_product, 
            acc.id_subdivision, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            SUM(count) AS total
        FROM 
            connacc_detail 
            INNER JOIN acceptance acc ON acc.number = num_acc 
        WHERE 
            acc.id_subdivision != 9 
        GROUP BY 
            code_spec_product, 
            code_spec_detail, 
            acc.id_subdivision
    ) a 
GROUP BY 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    a.code_spec_detail
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, это из-за того, что вы используете конструкцию

```
GROUP BY 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    a.code_spec_detail
```

Так как у вас сумма одинаковая, у вас две из трех записей получаются одинаковые и они группируются. Из трех записей получается 2. Уберете `GROUP BY` получите одну запись.

Назначьте конструкции `SUM(count)` псевдоним при помощи `AS`, например,

```
SUM(count) AS total
```

и добавьте группировку этот столбец

```
GROUP BY 
    a.code_spec_product, 
    a.id_subdivision, 
    a.code_spec_detail
    total
```

Если же вам нужна сумма всех столбцов, убирайте группировку вообще.

Comment: Нужна общая сумма только объединенных столбцов. Ваш совет помог, спасибо. Итоговый sql-запрос напишу в вопросе.